How to adjust text/page formatting in Latex for CV?

While making europass cv in latex I used \ecvblueitem to make two sections (section 1 and section 2). Section 1 has text around half of the page whereas Section 2 has text exceeding one page.
(1) How can I make the Section 2 to continue from the remaining part of the Page 1 and continue the remaining text to another page?
(2) The text of Section 2 not by itself continuing to the next page (i.e. Page 3) as can be seen at the end of Page 2 it is exceeding the page size.
Following is the code for this:
\documentclass[english,a4paper]{europasscv}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
  \begin{europasscv}

 \ecvpersonalinfo

 \ecvbigitem{Text here}{Text here}

    \ecvsection{Text here 2}
    
\ecvblueitem{Section 1}{

text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3}


\ecvblueitem{Section 2}{

text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline

4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline 

4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline 

 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline 
 
 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline 
 
 
  4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline 
  
  
 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline 
 
 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline 
 
  4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline 
  
   4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4 \newline
   
      4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4
      
         4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4} 


\end{europasscv}

\end{document}



This is a result of the europasscv latex class forcing each section to be entirely on one page. The best solution here is to create a "third" section with no name at the point where you want the second page to start. See below code for an example on how to do this with your document.


\documentclass[english,a4paper]{europasscv}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
  \begin{europasscv}

 \ecvpersonalinfo

 \ecvbigitem{Text here}{Text here}

    \ecvsection{Text here 2}
    
\ecvblueitem{Section 1}{

text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3}


\ecvblueitem{Section 2}{

text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline

4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline

4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline

4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline

 
4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline} 
 

\ecvblueitem{}{
4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline

  
4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline 
 
4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline 
 
4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline 
  
4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4 \newline
   
4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4 \newline
      
4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4} 


\end{europasscv}

\end{document}

